# Java Split into 3 Fields

Tags: java

I have a String that looks like **"NAME:City~FORMAT:S~PRINT:true"**

I want to split and assign the value of "City" to field1, "S" to field2, and true to field3 (Boolean).

I know I can grind through this code with brute force, but is there a way to parse the value of the 2nd split into the fields without doing some sort of check on a subscript to see if it is an odd value (e.g. subscript 0 is the NAME, but I want subscript 1, which is "City").

```
   for (String element : text.split("~")) {
        for (String rule : element.split(":")) {
            System.out.println(rule);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also avoid looping by doing something similar to this:

```
String[] flds = text.split("NAME:|~FORMAT:|~PRINT:");
String field1 = flds[1];
String field2 = flds[2];
String field3 = flds[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do

```
for (String element : text.split("~")) {
   System.out.println(element.split(":")[1]);
}
```

[`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) returns an array, and you want the second element, which has index `1`.